# SQL Query to select records that checks for at least one valid record with criteria given

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was working on formulating a query for a eligibility table with a user can have different eligibilities.

Table will have the below given format.

```
id | start_date | end_date | status | user_id
---------------------------------------------
```

For this I have to get all users with active eligibility. Query for the same is added below.

```
select *
from users u
  inner join eligibility e on users.id=eligibility.user_id
where e.start_date <= '2019-03-22'
  and e.end_date >= '2019-03-22'
  and e.status<> 'inactive'
```

This works fine and I'm getting eligibile users when there is at least one valid eligibility record with the criteria given in the query.

Now *I have to check all ineligible users* using these records.

Basically we will have to select users with no valid eligibility records. 
If user has at least one eligibility record then user is termed as eligible.

Sample data and expected results are added below.

Users table :-

```
id | first_name | last_name
---------------------------
1  |    John    |  Doe
2  |    Sam     |  Ronald
3  |   Alice    |  Wayne
4  |    Dean    |  Marcus
5  |    Bony    |  Ignatius
6  |    Kim     |  Pharm
7  |   Tony     |  Ryan
```

Eligibility table :-

```
id | start_date | end_date    | status | user_id
-------------------------------------------------
 1    2018-06-23  2018-12-31  | active |   1
 2    2018-06-23  2019-01-30  | active |   1
 3    2018-06-23  2018-12-31  | active |   3
 4    2018-06-23  2019-12-22  | active |   3
 5    2018-06-23  2018-12-31  |inactive|   4
 6    2018-06-23  2019-03-10  | active |   4
 7    2018-06-23  2018-12-31  | active |   5
 8    2018-06-23  2019-12-31  | active |   5
 9    2018-06-23  2018-01-31  | active |   6
 10   2018-06-23  2019-12-24  | active |   6
 11   2018-06-23  2018-12-31  |inactive|   7
 12   2018-06-23  2019-02-22  | active |   7
 13   2018-06-23  2019-12-31  | active |   1
 14   2018-06-23  2019-12-31  | active |   3
```

With this data  and current date, users with Id : 1,3,5 and 6 are eligible.
And users with id 2(doesn't have eligibility record),4 and 7 are ineligible if you look at the data.

NB : status 'active' doesn't mean its active. We have to check the date range also.

Now I want to know how can I query ineligible users.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: I'm using MS SQL Server

Comment: Then you can remove the <mysql> tag.

Comment: I did that. Now,can you help me with the solution?

Comment: *"I have tried some options but nothing worked for getting all ineligible users."* Could you post those attempts? Why didn't they work as you expected or return the results you wanted? Could you share some sample data and the expected results you're after for that sample?

Comment: @Larnu Totally agree, sample data and expected results always the best.

Comment: I've updated the question with data and expected results. Please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the conditions for an eligibile user:

```
e.start_date <= '2019-03-22' and e.end_date >= '2019-03-22' and e.status<> 'inactive'
```

So if there is not a row for a user in the table `eligibility` that satisfies these conditions then that user is ineligible.
You can use `not exists`:

```
select u.* from users u 
where not exists (
  select 1 from eligibility
  where 
    u.id = user_id 
    and
    start_date <= '2019-03-22' and end_date >= '2019-03-22'
    and 
    status <> 'inactive'
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try between before?

```
select * from users u
where exists(select 0 from eligible e
where u.user_id = e.user_id and 
'2019-03-22' between e.start_date and e.end_date and
e.status<> 'inactive')
```

Comment: I've updated the question with data and expected results. Please have a look

Answer (score 0):

What does this give you:

```
select * from users u
LEFT join eligibility e on users.id=eligibility.user_id
where e.user_id is NULL
```

Comment: This won't work as there user id for every eligibility record.

Comment: I've updated the question with data and expected results. Please have a look

Comment: @Sachin, it will work. i can see straight away from your sample data, Sam Ronald's id is absent from the eligibility table. The date range criteria can be added back to narrow the dataset .

Comment: That is one of a case where user has no eligibility record. But if you look at user : Dean Marcus , he has two records in eligibility table which are not valid as per current date. ie : expired eligibilities